# How do re-download the OBB file of an Android Application if it is accidentally deleted?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android Application which uses the OBB file as the database for storing media files. Suppose, if the user deletes the OBB file from his phone by mistake, I am not able to download it again. How to re-direct the OBB file download via Google Playstore like it happens in the Asphalt mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

The main activity in your application (the one started by your launcher icon) is responsible for verifying whether the expansion files are already on the device and initiating the download if they are not.

Starting the download using the Downloader Library requires the following procedures:

1.Check whether the files have been downloaded.

```
boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
        String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, xf.mIsBase,
        xf.mFileVersion);
        if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName, xf.mFileSize, false))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

2.Start the download by calling the static method.

```
DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(Context c, PendingIntent notificationClient, Class<?> serviceClass)
```

3.When the `startDownloadServiceIfRequired()` method returns anything other than `NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED`, create an instance of IStub by calling

```
DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub(IDownloaderClient client, Class<?> downloaderService).
```

You can follow the detail implementation steps here. https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Download